# Android :adding tabs in fragments using view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe, android-tabs

I have implement swiping in view pager with three pages i.e Fragment 1,Fragment 2 and Fragment 3. Now i want to add tab-host, which contains 5 tabs with different views in Fragment 3. Then finally have 7 pages in view pager. But tabs should be visible in Fragment 3 only.

How can i add tabs in fragment 3?

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    // page adapter between fragment list and view pager
    public static PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    // view pager
    public ViewPager mPager;
    // activity data
    public String p2text, p3text;
    public static List<Fragment> fragments;// = buildFragments();
    // / ArrayList<String> categories = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"};
    ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    static final String LOG_TAG = "HomeActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fragments = new ArrayList<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>();
        categories.add("1");
        categories.add("2");
        categories.add("3");
        categories.add("4");
        categories.add("5");
        categories.add("6");
        categories.add("7");

        addFragments(FragmentMore.class.getName(), 1);
        addFragments(FragmentMain.class.getName(), 2);
        addFragments(FragmentChatView.class.getName(), 3);

        mPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments, categories);
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(1);

    }

    public void addFragments(String className, int position) {
        // List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragments = new
        // ArrayList<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>();

        // (int i = 0; i<categories.size(); i++) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("position", position);
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, className, b));
        // }

        // return fragments;
    }

    public void removeFragments(String className, int position) {
        // List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragments = new
        // ArrayList<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>();

        // (int i = 0; i<categories.size(); i++) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("position", position);
        fragments.remove(Fragment.instantiate(this, className, b));
        // }

        // return fragments;
    }

    private List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> buildFragments() {
        List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>();

        for (int i = 0; i < categories.size(); i++) {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("position", i);
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentSearch.class.getName(), b));
        }

        return fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onPause");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some code, please?

Comment: I have added code. I want to add tabs in FragmentChatView.class

Comment: This is not trivial. Just curious, are you doing this as a college project or work?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what your are trying to do is done here:

- Api Demos code: [FragmentNestingTabs](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentNestingTabs.java) and [FragmentTabsFragment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabsFragment.java)
- App with almost all Android functionalities [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hmh.api) in App/Fragment/Nesting Tabs/ (last tab)

With these two links you should be able to develop what you are looking for.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's not simple to add tabs with ViewPager. A Google webpage is @ [Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#tabs). Search text for "Add Tabs to the Action Bar". It uses **ActionBar**.TabListener and **ActionBar**.addTab to make the GUI.

A full sample code is @ [FragmentTabs.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabs.java). I think this is the same code as the Google page.

There is also a Google project @ [SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html), which I have used and it works. There may be a minor issue with the build.gradle file.

**Notes**: The Google webpage uses `ActionBar.TabListener` and `addTab` method which is deprecated by API 21. But...it is easier to implement. If you're doing this as a college project, using the ActionBar may be the wiser choice, just as a thought.

Good luck, have fun, keep us posted...